# Button image changes back when singleitemview is closed and reopened

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a listview which when clicked on listitem opens a new singleitenview activity
The singleitenm view consists of a button which is used to add the corresponding listitem to favorites activity(if not yet added) and changes the button color to yellow indicating it is added to favoorites or else gray if not in favorites
Till here everything works fine but if i close the singleitemview and reopen it the button color changes back to previous color but still in facvorites

What shall i do to  retain the button color

**onitemclick of my list activity**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            Product pro = productListAdapter.getItem(position);

                            String favimg = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite)).toString();

    try
    {
        String hi = "this is testint";


        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(pro);

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), SingleItemView.class);
        intent.putExtra("selected item", jsonInString);


        ;

        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    //  startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {}  



}
```

**favbtn of singleitemview activity**

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemButton1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            products=new ArrayList<Product>();
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            String jsonObj = extras.getString("selected item");


            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            try
            {
                Product pro = mapper.readValue(jsonObj, Product.class);

                if (checkFavoriteItem(pro)) {

                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(SingleItemView.this, pro);

                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,
                                   SingleItemView.this.getResources().getString(R.string.remove_favr),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } else {
                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(SingleItemView.this, pro);
                    Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this,
                                   SingleItemView.this.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {};





        });
```